# Calculating total derivatives using partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm having trouble to understand how do I relate the partial derivatives to total derivates.

I have this problem:

Calculate $\frac{d(x^{{e}^{x}})}{dx}$, using the partial derivatives of $ W = x^{{e}^{y}}$

I noticed that $\frac{d(x^{{e}^{x}})}{dx}$ = $\frac{\partial(W)}{\partial(x)}+\frac{\partial(W)}{\partial(y)} \frac{d(y)}{d(x)}$, when I use y = x

Can I always do that? If yes, why?
Or is it just a coincidence and I'm doing it wrong?

And How can I do $\frac{d^2(x^{{e}^{x}})}{dx^2}$ using the partial derivatives of W?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^{e^x}$. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $g(x)=(x,x)$ be the identity function. And, as you defined, we have $W(x,y)=x^{e^y}$.

Then it is easy to see that $f=W\circ g$.

What we want to calculate is

$$\frac{d f}{d x}=\frac{d (x^{e^x})}{d x}.$$

Using the chain rule

\begin{align*}
\frac{d f}{d x} &= \frac{d (W\circ g)}{d x} \\
&= \left[\begin{array}[cc] 
 & \frac{\partial W}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}
 \end{array}\right]\nabla g \\
&= \left[\begin{array}[cc] 
& \frac{\partial W}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}
 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}[c] 
& \frac{d g_1}{d x}\\ \frac{d g_2}{d x}
 \end{array}\right]\\
&= \left[\begin{array}[cc] 
& \frac{\partial W}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}
 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}[c] 
& 1\\ 1
 \end{array}\right]\\
&=\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}.
\end{align*}

So, this formula is just applying the chain rule to the right functions.